# The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/firebase_app.js?v=bdc3ec1e' does not provide an export named 'getApps'

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vite

Haven't had an issue until all of a sudden today. I have not changed any firebase.js code or any firebase rules anytime recently that could cause such an error. I'm using Vue 3 with Vite. I'm currently on Firebase version 10.0.0 which is latest.

**Error:**

*Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/firebase_app.js?v=bdc3ec1e' does not provide an export named 'getApps' (at firebase.js:1:471)*

**firebase.js**

```
import { getApps, initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, sendEmailVerification } from "firebase/auth";
const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_KEY,
authDomain: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_PROJECT_ID,
storageBucket: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
appId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_APP_ID,
measurementId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID
};
const apps = getApps()
const firebaseApp = !apps.length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : apps[0]
const firebaseAuth = getAuth(firebaseApp)
const getCurrentUser = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
const unsub = onAuthStateChanged(firebaseAuth, user => {
unsub()
resolve(user)
}, reject)
})
export const createUserWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => {
return firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
}
export const signInWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => {
return firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
}
// send Email Verification to user after sign up
export const sendEmailVerificationToUser = () => {
return sendEmailVerification(firebaseAuth.currentUser)
}

// reauthenticateUser, updatePassword
export const reauthenticateUser = (password) => {
const user = firebaseAuth.currentUser
const cred = firebaseAuth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email, password)
return user.reauthenticateWithCredential(cred)
}
export const updatePassword = (password) => {
return firebaseAuth.currentUser.updatePassword(password)
}
export { firebaseApp, firebaseAuth, getCurrentUser }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. To solve it I did the following:

1. delete pacakge-lock.json
2. run "npx rimraf ./**/node_modules" on my project folder to remove node
   modules
3. run npm install

Hope it Helps

Comment: Yep. This is what ended up working for me too. Will mark this as answer.