# No export named 'initializeApp' in Firebase when setting up Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vite

I am trying to intialize Firebase like this:

```
// importing configuration from firebasem and necessary SDK (Software Development Kit) stuff
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"

// setting up firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
    .........
  };

// set up app in firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

However, I am getting this error in my console when I try to run the app:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/firebase_app.js?v=d47eede3' does not provide an export named 'initializeApp' (at index.js:6:10).

But Visual Studio Code does not throw any errors.

I have no idea why this error is appearing, since I carefully followed Firebase's documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdk-and-initialize.

Could it be a problem with vite? I've tried deleting package-lock.json and node_modules folder, and then using "npm-install" to reinstall all dependencies, but that did not work.

Comment: Wondering if you found a solution for this, since I just ran into the same issue, and I only see other people with the same question but no answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The requested module '/node\_modules/.vite/deps/firebase\_app.js?v=bdc3ec1e' does not provide an export named 'getApps'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76662168/the-requested-module-node-modules-vite-deps-firebase-app-jsv-bdc3ec1e-does)